# How to prove logic expressions with numbers in them with truth table

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

I'm studying logic gates and expressions using truth tables and I'm really struggling with the concept.
Here's on assignment I have and it would really help if I can see an example on how to go about solving these kind of examples.
The assignment is to prove that this statement is right using a truth table.
A(1+ ¬AC)+ ¬A = 1
Any help would be greatly appreciated with this!
Thanks in advanced for taking the time to help.

Comment: $1$ in this context is the same as "True", a tautology.  Similarly, $0$ in this context is the same as "False."

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Filling in the truth table is a straightforward task, but keep in mind `1 + anything  = 1` and `A + ¬A = 1` as you fill in:

```
A C ¬A  ¬AC   1+¬AC  A(1+¬AC) A(1+¬AC)+¬A
0 0 
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Try filling in one column at a time and if everything goes right, you must see all `1`s in the last column.

---

Filling in the table you should get

```
A C ¬A  ¬AC   1+¬AC  A(1+¬AC) A(1+¬AC)+¬A
0 0  1   0     1        0        1
0 1  1   1     1        0        1
1 0  0   0     1        1        1
1 1  0   0     1        1        1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Yeah, i understand how to fill out the truth table. Its just i'm confused on how to go about and solve this to get 1 in the end. for example !A*c does that mean !A&c or actual multiplication. If it's at all possible can you show me how to solve this step by step as an example so I can understand more. Again thank you so much for taking the time in helping me!

Comment: Ah okay `A + B` means `A or B`

Comment: `AB` means `A and B`

Comment: I'll fill in the table for you. Ask if something isn't clear

Comment: If it helps think of `and` in terms of switching a lamp: https://circuitglobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/AND-GATE-FIG-4-compressor.jpg

Comment: `A=1` means you turn `on` the switch `A`. Similarly `A=0` means you turn `off` the switch `A`

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help! Now it makes sense.